# ASP.NET WebPages use html extension

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-webpages

I'm trying to use [ASP.NET WebPages](http://www.asp.net/web-pages) to make sense of an existing site which uses static .html files (about 500 of them).  Unfortunately, my SEO person is requiring that the site maintains its existing directory / filenames, so I need to use .html.

After finding [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5148405/3421), I tried adding the extension in `web.config` under `compilation/buildProviders/` as:

```
<add extension=".html" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider"/>
```

And adding an Assembly as well:

```
<add assembly="System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

This still doesn't render the page.  It is simply output as source.  I also created a `Global.asax` at the root of the project and added this under `Application_Start()`:

```
System.Web.Razor.RazorCodeLanguage.Languages.Add(
    "html", new System.Web.Razor.CSharpRazorCodeLanguage());
System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpHandler.RegisterExtension("html");
```

Still had no effect.  Unfortunately, I'm drawing a blank on Google.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to map requests for *.html to .cshtml files, or are you attempting to add Razor code to existing .html files and want them processed by ASP.NET?

Comment: I want to `.html` files to automagically be parsed by Razor.  By default, this action is performed on .cshtml files.  90% of what I'm looking for is `@Layout` and `@RenderPage` (for including other pages).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I happened upon this question while trying to solve the same problem - although in my case, for curiosity's sake.

Here's what you need in your web.config file:

```
<system.web>
   <compilation>
      <buildProviders>
         <add extension=".html"
              type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider, System.Web.WebPages.Razor"/>
      </buildProviders>
   </compilation>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
   <handlers>
      <add name="Html" verb="*" path="*.html"
           type="System.Web.Webpages, WebPageHttpHandler"/>
   </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

This isn't enough on its own, though! We need to register the extension with `WebPageHttpHandler`.
Normally, you'd be able to do stuff like this in the `_AppStart` file - unfortunately, when the application starts (i.e when `_AppStart` executes), it iterates over the items in the SupportedExtensions of WebPageHttpHandler, so we can't actually register the extension in AppStart.
What I did is I made a new .dll assembly with the `PreApplicationStartMethod` attribute, as seen [here](http://dailydotnettips.com/2011/08/27/initialize-assemblies-using-preapplicationstartmethodattribute-aspnet4-app/), but you can also do it inside the `Global.asax` file's `Application_Start` method.

Finally, we also need to add "html" as an extension to the `RazorCodeLanguage.Languages` dictionary, so that the Razor engine can figure out how to compile the template.

Example Global.asax file:

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" %>
<script runat="server">
   void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
   {
      System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpHandler.RegisterExtension("html");
      var languages = System.Web.Razor.RazorCodeLanguage.Languages;
      languages.Add("html", languages["cshtml"]);
   }       
</script>
```

Comment: +1 This works like a charm :) Though I was able to register in `_AppStart.chtml` without issue.

Comment: You really shouldn't be able to - the `ExecuteStartPage(HttpApplication)` method in `ApplicationStartPage.cs` ends up calling `ExecuteStartPageInternal` with `WebPageHttpHandler.GetRegisteredExtensions()` as an IEnumerable. `GetRegisteredExtensions` returns a read-only wrapper for the _supportedExtensions array, but modifying that array likewise modifies the wrapper. `ExecuteStartPageInternal` iterates over this read-only wrapper until it finds an _AppStart with an extension in that wrapper - but because it's iterating over the wrapper, we can't modify the underlying array inside _AppStart.

Comment: I tinkered with this on default scaffolding (VS2013) for `ASP.net Web Site Razor 3` (not application so there is no `global.asax` even) and AFAIK, that _is_ WebPages. More spooky stuff - didn't need the `handler` section, `buildProvider` was enough. Tinkered further and added more random things like ".edsf" and boom - razor code, extension-less, etc. etc (just no intellisense). I have no idea why I'd ever actually use it though, so chalk it up to tinkering :)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use routing. Are you using webforms or MVC?
Global.asax is a good start. Add the complete code here:

```
namespace Name
{
    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {

        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }

        protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.MapPageRoute("Route1", "OldPage.html", "~/NewPage.aspx");

        }

        protected void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Obviously you don't want to manually add 500 routes but you can add url filters.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.ASPX

> ASP.NET routing enables you to use URLs that do not have to map to
>   specific files in a Web site.

Comment: I'm actually using ASP.NET WebPages so that I can just make files in the package and upload to Azure.  I'd rather not involve MVC or WebForms.  But I'd like to be able to re-use the templates and content later if the project evolves.

Comment: My apologies, maybe there is a simpler way to do it within WebPages. The only easy solution I know of is to use MVC... define {resource}.html in your routing table and specify a Controller, and then have the controller pick up a View based on the {resource} specified. I fear for your sanity if you  have to manually reroute 500 urls. PS. MVC uses Razor too.

Comment: I have done some in MVC and that's where I learned of Razor.  As for the routes, that's why I'm shooting for this plan:  I can automate creating the files on the filesystem, just need to use .html in ALL the URLs instead of .cshtml.