# Import, migrate or otherwise create a new VS project or solution for current ASP site that has none

Tags: visual-studio-2008

8yr old Classic ASP site needs to be migrated into a new VS solution or project as it never was created with one and I need to modify, but I am having no luck I have tried copying to InetPub and building from there but in VS it only wants to load each file individually which is a hassle.

ANY ideas tips or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Attempting to use VWD 2008, but ready to just go 2010.

Answer (score 0):

[@Possible Baloch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/404638/possible-baloch) provided [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462752/will-visual-studio-2010-support-classic-asp/3353972#3353972) in the question titled "[will visual studio 2010 support classic asp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462752/will-visual-studio-2010-support-classic-asp)"

> open your site using the Open->Website under MS VS 2008 or 2010
>
> then save it as a solution. you site is now in a solution ;) I hope this helps