# How to create ASP project in Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, asp-classic

Is it possible to create an "ASP only" project in visual studio with any version? I know "ASP" is an old technology even though we have some "asp" projects. So can any one help me software requirements for "ASP". (If I search in google it will search ASP.net not "only asp").

Comment: Have you tried googling with the keyword "-.net"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3453835/269126), which points you to a CodeProject article on [Debugging Classic ASP ( VBScript ) in Visual Studio 2008](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28792/Debugging-Classic-ASP-VBScript-in-Visual-Studio-20). That should meet your needs.