# Possible to have both ASP and ASP.NET in same Cassini debug session?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis, asp-classic, cassini

I'm doing some debugging of asp.net and noticed that my classic asp stuff in the same project isn't working in cassini on windows xp sp3 using visual studio 2010 SP1Rel.  Do I need to add vbrun.dll to cassini or is it even possible to debug classic asp files in a cassini debug session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Cassini webserver doesnot run Classic ASP

You can use this link as it has been answered below:-

[Debugging Classic ASP in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453762/debugging-classic-asp-in-visual-studio-2010)