# Any way to run classic asp in visual studio 2010 without IIS?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp-classic

I am working with a page in Classic ASP in Visual Studio 2010. For other ASP.NET projects, I have been able to run and debug them within VS, but [I've just discovered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453762/debugging-classic-asp-in-visual-studio-2010) that this is not possible with Classic ASP pages.

I would like to be able to use IIS or third-party software as I've seen mentioned in other posts, but I don't have IIS installed locally and do *not* have admin access to my own machine. I do have VS 2005 and VS 2008, but am not sure whether there are workarounds involving older versions of VS.

Does anyone know if this is even possible?

(Note: I plan to convert this page to ASP.NET in the future, but would like to be able to run it first :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No is the simple answer to your question.  The dev server which comes with VS supports ASP.net but not classic ASP.

IIS Express does support classic ASP and can be used in conjunction with VS, and you may be able to install it without admin privileges, obviously I don't know the precise details of your setup.

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/using-iis-express/running-iis-express-without-administrative-privileges

There's also a product called Active Local Pages, which is a sort of IE plugin which enables IE to run ASP code client side.  It's not ideal but it's better than nothing.

http://www.activelocalpages.com/