# Can't debug ASP Classic on VS2013 and IISExpress: symbols not loaded for the document

Tags: visual-studio, asp-classic, iis-express

I'm trying to debug an **ASP Classic** application in **Visual Studio 2013** running on **IIS Express**.

All the documentation talk about IIS, I didn't find yet any discussion about IIS Express. When I attach the debugger to the IISExpress.exe process, my brake points become circles with a yellow triangles saying:

```
The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.
```

Is there a particular way of debugging ASP Classic?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453762/debugging-classic-asp-in-visual-studio-2010. Personally, I just use friendly error messages for debugging

Comment: It can't be a duplicate because the question you are referring to talks about IIS (not IIS Express). As I mentioned in my question, there are plenty of articles about ASP Classic and IIS. I'm looking for articles ou answers that explain how to debug ASP Classic when running on IIS Express.